# Time axis: Remove scale points with no data

Tags: d3.js

I have a dataset which I am plotting. I've modelled it as a network, and have used a force-directed layout to display it, except that I have constrained the layout such that on the x-axis, the nodes are arranged according to time.

An example of what I've done so far is here on my own website: http://www.ericmajinglong.com/force/force.html

As you can see, I have one time axis. The axis scale is derived from the data. However, you'll notice a big gap in the middle.

I understand the concept of scales, where I have a domain and a range, and a scale basically maps the domain to the range. I have a few questions, however.

1. I was wondering if it might be possible, **without** creating two horizontal time axes, to exclude empty months?
2. Instead of an linear scale, would I have to go to an ordinal scale?
3. Would there be any disadvantages to going to an ordinal scale instead of a time scale?

Code is not posted here for brevity, but I have it at: http://www.ericmajinglong.com/force/force.js

Comment: As Pablo has pointed out in his answer already, you would have to use an ordinal scale. I just want to add that if the time dimension is important (and I'm guessing it is), it might be better to show the empty gap to emphasize the fact that there is a gap.

Comment: Yes, Lars, you're right. The time dimensions is important, and as a grad student in the life sciences, I know that it's commonplace to put a bent line or gap of some sort to indicate that there's a break in the time axis. Do you know how that might be done?

Comment: I think two axes (wrapped in a single function) are the way to go here.

Answer (score 4):

You can probably use an ordinal scale, but in that case you should make sure that the domain is sorted, and add some mark between the two intervals so the user of the visualization understand that there is a a period not shown. Another option is to create a custom scale that automatically shorten gaps in the data, but will still to add special markers to indicate missing time periods.

If you use an ordinal scale instead of a time scale, you will need to format the axis manually.

**EDIT: Add a small example of how a custom scale may be implemented**

I would implement a custom scale as a closure with accessors.

```
function customScale() {

    // Scale attributes
    var domain = [0, 1],  // Default domain
        range = [0, 1];   // Default range

    function scale(x) {
        var y = 0;
        // Compute the output value...
        return y;
    }

    // Domain and Range Accessors
    scale.domain = function(value) {
        if (!arguments.length) { return domain; }
        domain = value;
        return scale;
    };

    // range accessor...

    return scale;
}
```

And then configure and use the scale

```
var scale = customScale()
    .domain([0, 10])
    .range([2, 3]);

console.log(scale(5));
```

Using a custom scale will probably implies to create custom axis as well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Pablo! Would you be kind enough to write some sample code that illustrates what you've said? I'm not sure how to create a custom scale here... total d3 newbie right now.

Comment: The custom scale can be created using the reusable chart pattern, I added an example above. If you are just beginning with D3, you should probably use the ordinal chart, implementing a custom scale and custom axis generator may be overkill.